# Testing whether a matrix of trig values is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I just want to check that the matrix below is not positive definite:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$$

I think that it is not because the upper left 1*1 determinant is just $cos(\theta)$ and this is not positive for every value of $\theta$

Is this correct?

Comment: It's positive-definite for _some_ values of $\theta$. Mainly, for $\theta$ between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: more generally $\cos \theta > 0 \Rightarrow \theta \in \left ( 2n\pi-\pi/2,2n\pi+\pi/2 \right )$

Answer (score 2):

You'll just have to see that this is a rotation and then go back to the definition of definiteness. $R_\theta$ is positively definite if $u\cdot R_\theta u>0$ for all $u\ne 0$. Now we have thhat $u\cdot R_\theta u=|u|^2\cos\theta > 0$ for all $u\ne 0$ if and only if $\cos\theta > 0$.